# How to make a responsive step bar in html css

Tags: css

I want to make a responsive step bar with year on top side of step circle and text in bottom of the circle like this one:
 [image]

Here is my html code.

```
<div class="container">
      <ul class="progressbar">
        <li>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li id="last-child"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Sameed-Ul-Hassan/pen/vbZpyV)

The problem is I am not getting how to add these years, circle in start and arrow in the end. Please help me how I can do this and make it responsive.I'll be very thankful to you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. thanks

```css
  .container {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: 100px auto; 
  }
  .progressbar {
      counter-reset: step;
  }
  .progressbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 16.6%;
      float: left;
      font-size: 10px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: #444972;
  }
  .progressbar li:before {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      content: counter(step);
      counter-increment: step;
      line-height: 30px;
      border: 3px solid #444972;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
  }

  .progressbar li:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 3px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #444972;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  #last-child:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 3px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #444972;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
#last-child:before {
     display: none;
  }
  .progressbar li:first-child:after {
      /*content: none;*/
  }

  #circle{
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7%;
    top: 16.29%;
    color: #444972;
  }

.outer{position:realative}

.year{
  position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
}

.progressbar{position:relative;}

.progressbar:before{
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    left: -10px;
    top: 12px;
}
.progressbar:after{
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid black;
    right: 63px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <ul class="progressbar">
        <li>
          <div class="outer"><p class="year">1990</p>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</div></li>
          <li>
          <div class="outer"><p class="year">1990</p>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</div></li>
        <li>
          <div class="outer"><p class="year">1990</p>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</div></li>
        <li>
          <div class="outer"><p class="year">1990</p>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</div></li>
        <li>
          <div class="outer"><p class="year">1990</p>Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</div></li>
          <li id="last-child"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use label with in your li and try this

```
 label{
    position: absolute;
    top:-40%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    font-size:18px;
  }
```

```css
.container {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: 100px auto; 
  }
  .progressbar {
      counter-reset: step;
  }
  .progressbar li {
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 16.6%;
      float: left;
      font-size: 10px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: #444972;
  }
  .progressbar li:before {
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      content: counter(step);
      counter-increment: step;
      line-height: 30px;
      border: 3px solid #444972;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
  }

  .progressbar li:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 3px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #444972;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
  #last-child:after {
      width: 100%;
      height: 3px;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #444972;
      top: 15px;
      left: -50%;
      z-index: -1;
  }
#last-child:before {
     display: none;
  }
  .progressbar li:first-child:after {
      /*content: none;*/
  }

  #circle{
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 7%;
    top: 16.29%;
    color: #444972;
  }
  
  label{
    position: absolute;
    top:-40%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    font-size:18px;
  }
  
  /*for circle use this class*/
  .dot {
   height: 18px;
   width: 18px;
   background-color: #444972;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
    top:8px;
    left: -60%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
  
    /*for triangle use this class*/
  .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:78px;
    border-top: 12px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #444972;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <ul class="progressbar">
        <li>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <label>1998</label>
        Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>
           <label>2004</label>
          Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>
           <label>2006</label>
          Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>
           <label>2014</label>
          Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li>
           <label>2015</label>
          Visionet was founded lorem ipsum dolor sit amet New York USA by Arshad Masood</li>
          <li id="last-child">
          <span class="triangle"></span>
          </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I want.